# How to load dynamically path under inner html in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi all i want  to load videos  under iframe  static link working fine  but how to  put  under src
means what is correct way to use path variable under src

```
  var path = VIDEOS_BASE_URL + name + '.mp4';
        $('#player-wrapper').html('<iframe width="640" height="360" src= path frameborder="0" 
         allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>');
```

Comment: Try like this `src= "+path+"`.

Comment: Thanks swati  but when i add  was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Comment: Hi can you check html generated of above code does that path showing correctly ? or try `src="'+path+'"` as well.